# Проблемы с подключением Jquery

Tags: jquery

Вроде тема простая... скопировал ссылку вставил и готово. Но у меня что то пошло не так. Помогите разобраться где я ошибаюсь. Написал тестовую функцию для проверки подключения. блок тест не исчезает при нажатии.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test" onclick="$('#test'.hide ()">test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Так правильно, в самом `onclick` ошибка. `onclick="$(this).hide()"`

Comment: Скобочку ) поставьте после  test'

Answer (score 1):

Вы просто неверно записали код в событии `onclick`.

**Ваш пример:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test" onclick="$('#test'.hide()">Кликни на меня и я исчезну</div>
<!-- Нужно хоть иногда смотреть в консоль -->
```

---

**С поправкой:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test" onclick="$(this).hide()">Кликни на меня и я исчезну</div>
```

*P.S. В следующий раз давайте код в текстовом варианте, с картинки оочень не охотно переписывать..*